# Android Studio Setup For First time

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to run a Simple Hello World Application in Android Studio But Gradle could not solve the dependencies.

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration':app:_debugAndroidTestApkCopy'.> Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
 Required by:
     MyApplication:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
  > Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/javawriter-2.1.1.pom'.
```

Similar More errors came up in the Error stack

Comment: please post your `build.gradle`

Comment: is your pc behind a proxy?

Comment: `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.m1034198.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}`
build.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add below dependancies in app module build.gradle;

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'}
```

and use ;

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

instead of jcenter() in project level build.gradle, this will resolve the gradle dependancies.

Comment: Now It is giving me this Error in Gradle                                                          **5:25:44 PM Gradle sync started**
**5:25:46 PM Gradle sync failed: Connection refused: connect
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)**

Comment: Yes.It has been resolved needed to do HTTPS authentication.Thanks for the Help